# can't upload a file into file browser in hue in cloudera

Tags: hadoop, bigdata, data-science

I am new in Big data and hadoop , i made a file called test with hello world content and i wanted to upload it into file browser when try this it gives me an error says "failed to find data node check the cluster health " i tried to solve it by searching the answer in this website and i found that the problem is in cluster " cloudera manger " when i try to open it it gives me a message that is highly recommended that use 10 Rams but if you want to force open use the command force " My PC is 6 g ram and when downloading the system it was recommended 8 g ram bus i give the Virtual machine 5,5 g ram and it is flexible with me in using the system so what is the problem and how can i force start the cloudera manger ?[this is a screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hfs5c.jpg)